# postgres housekeeping: DELETE older records based on GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
agent_audit_log(id, agent_id, api/text, at/timestamp)
```

Currently, my housekeeping has

```
DELETE FROM agent_audit_log WHERE at < NOW()  - INTERVAL '60 days';
```

Instead of the above, I want to delete all audit logs more than 100 latest records for "**each**" agent_id.
This is as far as I have gotten

```
DELETE FROM agent_audit_log WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM agent_audit_log ORDER BY at DESC LIMIT 100);
```

But this needs to happen per agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem will be to select the right ids, but you can use

```
CREATE tABLE agent_audit_log(id int, agent_id int , api text, at timestamp)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO agent_audit_log VALUES (1,1,'A',now()), (2,1,'B',now()),(3,2,'A',now()), (4,2,'B',now())
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 4
> ```

```
DELETE FROM agent_audit_log 
  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM agent_audit_log GROUP BY agent_id);
```

> ```
> DELETE 2
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM agent_audit_log
```

| id | agent_id | api | at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 2023-06-16 22:11:16.919099 |
| 3 | 2 | A | 2023-06-16 22:11:16.919099 |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

```
INSERT INTO agent_audit_log VALUES (2,1,'A',now()), (4,2,'A',now()),(6,1,'A',now()), (6,2,'A',now())
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 4
> ```

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY agent_id ORDER BY at) rn 
  FROM agent_audit_log)
DELETE FROM agent_audit_log 
  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1);
```

> ```
> DELETE 4
> ```

```
  SELECT *
  FROM agent_audit_log
```

| id | agent_id | api | at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 2023-06-16 22:11:16.919099 |
| 3 | 2 | A | 2023-06-16 22:11:16.919099 |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Qm0tZnG)

Comment: It keeps only one record per agent. Is it possible to keep N records per agent? For instance, keep only the last 100 calls each agent made.

Comment: as i don't know which to keep you must ibevstgate how both appraches wor s taht ypu can adept them https://dbfiddle.uk/bF0BUEjD

Comment: That worked. Thank you. `WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY agent_id ORDER BY at DESC) rn 
  FROM agent_audit_log)
DELETE FROM agent_audit_log 
  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM CTE WHERE rn < 100);  `